# Insertion sort algorithm - not outputting

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

Here I have copied an insertion sort algorithm, I have edited it a little bit trying to add my own array to the code and output it, but I cannot seem to get it working.

What code should I add to display sorted values?

Can anyone help please? I've literally been at it all day - really new to coding & C#, thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] array = { "banana", "apple", "zelepphan", "dingleberry" }; //this is just an example array :)
            for(int x=0; x<array.Length;x++) {
               Console.WriteLine(array[x]); //I added this part to try and display the outputted array, doesn't work  
            }
            Console.ReadKey();                
        }

        static void InsertSort(IComparable[] array)
        {
            int i, j;

            for (i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                IComparable value = array[i];
                j = i - 1;
                while ((j >= 0) && (array[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
                {
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    j = j - 1;
                }
                array[j + 1] = value;                    
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't invoke sort method before printing

```
string[] array = { "banana", "apple", "zelepphan", "dingleberry" }; 
InsertSort(array);
for(int x=0; x<array.Length; x++)
   Console.WriteLine(array[x]);
```

current output is

```
apple
banana
dingleberry
zelepphan
```

Comment: Hey ASh, is it possible, if the array is { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday ,Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday..} to output : Friday Friday Monday Monday Thursday Thursday Tuesday Tuesday Wednesday Wednesday, which is alphabetical, instead of doing outputting one day in order? :)

Comment: @Yrneh, how did you create such array exactly? it should not compile, as far as I can see. but with `string[] array = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"}; ` the output is printed in alphabetical order

Comment: sorry, you're right. However, what I am trying to achieve is reading a text file which is unsorted, sorting it using this algorithm and then outputting like = Friday Friday Monday Monday Thursday Thursday Tuesday Tuesday Wednesday Wednesday. If that helps?

Comment: `string[] array = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesda‌​y","Thursday","Friday"};` will be sorted as you expect and print Friday Friday Monday Monday Thursday Thursday Tuesday Tuesday Wednesday Wednesday

Comment: Is it possible to read in a file and conduct the same sorting, then output it to the screen? Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: yes, it is possible. there is exampe of reading from file in the bottom of article about StreamReader: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx